# How can I compute the probability of X_1 being the largest among X_i’s

Tags: statistics, probability

How can I compute the probability of X_1 being the largest among X_i’s

The random variable X_i follows gamma(alpha_i,1).

I think that
P(X_i is the largest) = \prod_{j\ne i} P(X_i > X_j).

Am I right?

Comment: This is an interesting problem, but suited to stats.stackexchange.com instead. Take a look at the topic called "order statistics". A web search will find some resources.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't understand this notation:

> P(X_i is the largest) = \prod_{j\ne i} P(X_i > X_j).

Could you explain some more, please?